# connect ETIMEDOUT en un bucle While - NODE JS y MYSQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, while

Estoy probando un código NODE JS donde quiero insertar un registro en una tabla MYSQL y necesito que esto ocurra si se cumple una condición en un bucle "while".

El código es el siguiente:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const insert = () => {

    const connection =  mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database : 'test'
      });

      const sql = "insert into tmp (data) values ('value')"      

      connection.query(sql,  (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.end()  
       })
}


const main = async () => {
    
    
    let x = 1
    let y = 1
    while (y !== 30000){
        console.log(x)
        if ( x == 999 )
        {
            insert();
            
        }
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
    }
    
    }

main();
```

Lo interesante es que mientras la condición de salida del while es menor a 20000 `("while (y !== 20000)")` la inserción se hace sin problemas, pero cuando elevamos la condición a 30000 `("while (y !== 30000)")` entonces obtengo un `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`.

También pude detectar que la "inserción en la base de datos" se produce "al finalizar el bucle while".

1.- ¿Por qué NODE JS espera a insertar el registro en la BD solo después de finalizado el bucle while?;

2.- ¿No podría insertar el registro solamente en el momento que se cumple la condición `("if ( x == 999 )")`?

Comment: El problema es que nodeJS es single thread, y lo que estás haciendo con ese ciclo es mas o menos bloquear el hilo principal... es decir... tus conexiones a la base de datos quedan como "encoladas" hasta que el ciclo principal termine... Puede ser esa la causa de que te salga conexion timedout cuando el ciclo demora mas tiempo (por ejemplo 30000 vs 20000)

Comment: Muchas gracias Pipe por tus comentarios. Reemplacé el método  **mysql.createConnection** por **mysql.createPool** y logré que no me tiré un error. Pero lo que necesito, es que el **insert()** se ejecute cuando es instanciado y "no" cuando termine el bucle. lo extremadamente extraño aquí, es que "corriendo una llamada a una API"  despues del **insert()** "la ejecución esperada se produce "antes que termine el ciclo **while**". 

Ej.:

`        {
             insert();
             await ejecutaLlamada('probando');
        }
`
¿Alternativas sin necesidad de correr una API innecesaria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí encontré la justificación al problema en el que me econtraba. Espero que aporte a otro miembro de la comunidad.
https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ
What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU

Saludos.